# SVG use not working in Safari

Tags: html, svg, safari

Im using this svg tag in my `html` file. It works perfectly in Chrome, but in safari the icon doesn't appear

```
<svg width="25" height="23" viewBox="0 0 25 23">
       <use href="./icons.svg#helemet"></use>
 </svg>
```

any know why?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Safari doesn't support href yet, you need to use xlink:href instead.

href is a new feature of the upcoming SVG 2 specification. xlink:href is the SVG 1.1 version.

Chrome, Firefox and Edge support both xlink:href and href.

Comment: And then you'll need to update the SVG root element.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884930/svg-namespace-prefix-xlink-for-href-on-textpath-is-not-defined?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Safari just added support for `<use href='...'>` this week, but slightly older versions still need `xlink:href`.  So while it feels lame to use a deprecated attribute, it's the safest right now for cross-browser support.

Comment: @dmbaughman do you have a reference for that support? It would be good to update https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an update from the future 2019.
Just add `xlink:`

```
<svg role="img">
    <use xlink:href="/path/to/svg#id"></use>
</svg>
```

Works with IOS 12

Comment: this is exactly what Robert said in the first answer

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href) of `xlink:href`, you **should not use it** in new code anymore because this feature may cease to work at any time. If you **must** use it because of browser support (unlikely, but you never know), then the proposed procedures is to use both:

```html
<use href="some-id" xlink:href="some-id" ... />
```

Talking about browser support, according to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-svg_attributes_href), the `href` attribute is supported by >98% of tracked browsers. The last "big" browser that didn't support it was Safari, but they also support it since v12.1 which was released in 2019.

Comment: Worth noting `xlink:href` is also required by quite a few (if not most) graphic/office applications. That's probably the main reason why this legacy attribute is likely to stay supported for quite some time.