# How to make svg <image> element show up in safari/ios

Tags: svg, safari, leaflet

My scenario: I'm displaying a [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) map. A map has several tiles, each tile might contain one or more icons.
Here is how a tile might look like:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" pointer-events="none" width="256" height="256" viewBox="0 0 256 256" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(455px, -4px, 0px); opacity: 1;">
    <g></g>
    <image x="213.9375" y="252.875" width="19px" height="19px" href="data:image/png;base64,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" class="" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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" style="pointer-events: auto;"></image>
</svg>
```

Result in Chrome,Firefox (inspected via devtools):

[image]

In Safari however, the icons are not rendered. The element is there, but the picture is missing. Screenshot from [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/) for safari, ios6. The highlighted blue box is the  element (inspected via devtools again), showing that the element is in position, with the correct dimensions, but no image is showing:

[image]

What I **have** tried:

- Using absolute and relative url paths for the image resource instead of inline base64. Makes
  no difference. The image is also hosted on the same domain, no
  cross-domain issues apply.
- Using various combinations of xlink:href    and href (just
  xlink:href, just href, etc).

  - Modifying the image/svg tag. Added the appropriate namespaces and the xlink:href tag (default library only used href), as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43962207/1543677) suggestion.

What I **haven't** tried:

- Completely replacing the svg mechanism of leaflet with another
  (say...[canvas](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#canvas)). Much of the application relies on the svg
  renderer, so I'd rather not go there.

Are there any other suggestions I could try except replacing the svg renderer?

Minimum reproducible example:
https://jsfiddle.net/tocxvxy3/3/

Comment: have you tried without `transform: translate3d(455px, -4px, 0px);`?

Comment: @scraaappy No, because the translate code is added by leaflet in order to properly position the map, tile and icon in relation to each other. However, I don't think that translate3d is related anyhow, because the element is correctly positioned as shown in the 2nd picture.

Comment: The jsfiddle works/displays just the same for me on Safari as it does on Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @RobertLongson are you using Safari on iPhone? I'm not seeing the icon on iPhone.

Comment: No, I'm using Safari on a Mac. You could try reporting this as a bug to Apple.

Comment: Could you post the `JavaScript` code using the Leaflet library that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Have you found the solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try to directly put the png file name, intead of embbeding it in svg, as in leaflet examples http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/ , maybe the ios support is better this way?

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.5, -0.09], 13);

 L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
 }).addTo(map);

 var LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
  options: {
   shadowUrl: 'leaf-shadow.png',
   iconSize:     [50, 50],
   shadowSize:   [50, 64],
   iconAnchor:   [22, 94],
   shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
   popupAnchor:  [-3, -76]
  }
 });

 var greenIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: 'https://memegenerator.net/img/images/50x50/7452314.jpg', iconRetinaUrl: 'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2012/09/14/blogs/Fils-Aime/Fils-Aime-thumbLarge.jpg'});

 L.marker([51.5, -0.09], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#map {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id='map'></div>
```

There's also an iconRetinaUrl option if you want to try

```
var greenIcon = new LeafIcon({
  iconUrl: 'https://memegenerator.net/img/images/50x50/7452314.jpg',
  iconRetinaUrl: 'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2012/09/14/blogs/Fils-Aime/Fils-Aime-thumbLarge.jpg'
});
```

Comment: As I said in the question, I've already tried it: "Using absolute and relative url paths for the image resource instead of inline base64. Makes no difference. "