# Change foundation svg color on hover

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Hello so I've seen a lot of codes regarding the hover color change on svg's but I can't get it to work. The thing is I am using [foundation icons](http://zurb.com/playground/foundation-icon-fonts-3), and here is a sample code:

```
<img src="svgs/fi-mail.svg">
```

Any idea on changing the color on hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the SVG into a native `<svg>` tag and then you need to apply DOM traversal and CSS to change it. I have a quick snippet, that I modified from elsewhere, and you can use it to change the properties.

> You need to make the SVG to be an **inline SVG**. You can make use of
>   this script, by adding a class `svg` to the image:
>
> ```
> /*
>  * Replace all SVG images with inline SVG
>  */
> jQuery('img.svg').each(function(){
>     var $img = jQuery(this);
>     var imgID = $img.attr('id');
>     var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
>     var imgURL = $img.attr('src');
>
>     jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
>         // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
>         var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');
>
>         // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
>         if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
>             $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
>         }
>         // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
>         if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
>             $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
>         }
>
>         // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
>         $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');
>
>         // Replace image with new SVG
>         $img.replaceWith($svg);
>
>     }, 'xml');
>
> });
> ```
>
> And then, now if you do:
>
> ```
> .logo-img path {
>   fill: #000;
> }
> ```
>
> Or may be:
>
> ```
> .logo-img path {
>   background-color: #000;
> }
> ```
>
> This works!

**Reference:** [img src SVG changing the fill color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933430/img-src-svg-changing-the-fill-color/24933495/)

Comment: .logo-img path {
  fill: #000;
}

I don't understand this, where did you get .logo-img path?

Comment: You can set a background color to the svg element itself, assuming there isn't a path or rect covering the full svg area.

Comment: @FewFlyBy That's a reference from the original answer, I just gave you a guidance to do it. Not writing the code for you, none of us do that! `:)`

Comment: @FewFlyBy Clarified the reference. Have a look!

Comment: @PraveenKumar so my code will look like <img src="svgs/fi-mail.svg" class="svg"> now right?

Comment: @FewFlyBy Yup! You got it right. Do it and let me know... `:)`

Comment: Still doing it, nothing happens. haha will tell you right away

Comment: Sure... Give me a shout!

Comment: The img is wrapped in an <a href>.. Does it matter>

Comment: Thank you for your code but this is the one I have used http://jsfiddle.net/wuSF7/31/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the color of an SVG that is included via an IMG tag. You can only modify inline SVG through CSS.

But the Zurb Foundation Icons are normally included as web-font, where each icon is just a simple text character, which can be styled as any other text. The idea to include a single SVG icon via an IMG tag deviates from the Foundation documentation. Please refer to the „How to use“ section in the docs-article you linked above…