# How to use an SVG file in a SvgIcon in Material-UI

Tags: svg, material-ui

I've got an SVG file and I want to make an SvgIcon component out of it, how should I do that?

In the [documentation](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/svg-icon), all the examples use either predefined Material Icons or a strange notation of `<path d="M10 20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12 3 2 12h3v8z" />` which I have no idea what it is!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`<path />` is an SVG path, i.e. the internal bits of the SVG. the `SvgIcon` component really should be able to take a path, but it doesn't :(

instead you can create a component like https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/56c113217d7d05d8bb0712771b727df81984d04b/src/svg-icons/action/home.js

with your svg source in place of the `path`. (I recommend minifying it a bit using https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/)

Comment: the path is hard codec, cannot this be done by loading the svg like we do with png ?

Comment: i did not quite understand this answer :( i do not see the path to the svg file anywhere in this answer

Comment: There are 2 types of path in this whole issue.  There is the 1)path as in _where is the svg file located_ and then there is the 2) **SVG-specific** path that is a property of the SVG element that contains information on how to draw itself.

Answer (score 55):

### 1. Using `<Icon/>` component and an `<img/>` element

To use a SVG file as an icon, I used the `<Icon/>` component with an `<img/>` element inside, setting the `height: 100%` to the `img` element and `textAlign: center` to the `root` class of the `<Icon/>` component did the trick:

**JSX:**

```
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
...

<Icon classes={{root: classes.iconRoot}}>
  <img className={classes.imageIcon} src="/graphics/firebase-logo.svg"/>
</Icon>
```

**Styles:**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  imageIcon: {
    height: '100%'
  },
  iconRoot: {
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
});
```

**Result:**

[image: Material UI Drawer Icon from SVG]

**UPDATE**

As Lorenz Haase mentions in the comments, there is a slighly cuttting of the SVG at the bottom, which it can be fixed if we use flexbox and inherit width and height:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  imageIcon: {
    display: 'flex',
    height: 'inherit',
    width: 'inherit'
  }
});
```

### 2. Using `<SvgIcon/>` component and [`@svgr/webpack`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@svgr/webpack) webpack loader

According to the [official MUI documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#component-prop), we can use `<SvgIcon/>` component props and have a [`@svgr/webpack`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@svgr/webpack) loader to load `.svg` files using ESM imports.

> ### Component prop
>
> You can use the `SvgIcon` wrapper even if your icons are saved in the
> `.svg` format. [svgr](https://github.com/smooth-code/svgr) has loaders to import SVG files and use them
> as React components. For example, with webpack:

```js
// webpack.config.js
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
}

// ---
import StarIcon from './star.svg';

<SvgIcon component={StarIcon} viewBox="0 0 600 476.6" />
```

> It's also possible to use it with "url-loader" or "file-loader". It's
> the approach used by Create React App.

```js
// webpack.config.js
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: ['@svgr/webpack', 'url-loader'],
}

// ---
import { ReactComponent as StarIcon } from './star.svg';

<SvgIcon component={StarIcon} viewBox="0 0 600 476.6" />
```

Comment: I attempted this soloution, although it works I could not style it with a different colour, seems impossible

Comment: @MaxCarroll how would you style a SVG file in general not using material-ui? I don't think it can happen, it doesn't work that way. Check [img-src-svg-changing-the-styles-with-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933430/img-src-svg-changing-the-styles-with-css) for more details.

Comment: I have since discovered its because the svg had fill colours hard coded in the svg, with a little editing of the svg it worked. You can style a svg using css using the properties stroke and fill.

Comment: This is a great solution but could be optimized. As you can see in the image provided with the answer, the firebase logo gets cut off at the bottom (should look like this: https://firebase.google.com/brand-guidelines)

Adjusting the styles fixes this problem:

```const useStyles = makeStyles({
  imageIcon: {
    display: 'flex',
    height: 'inherit',
    width: 'inherit',
  }
});```

The image won't get cut off. 
The root style isnt necessary anymore and the image gets its dimensions from the parent Icon component.

Comment: @LorenzHaase I didn't notice that it gets cut at the bottom, nice catch. I'll check out the rules and I will update my answer, thank you.

Comment: Mthod 1 works but I cannot seem to change the color of the icon. Is that possible?

Comment: Not sure why this is not marked as the "right answer" but it worked like a charm

Comment: @ChristosLytras I have added an answer below but you should probably edit your answer to explain why setting the viewBox is important. I don't really understand what is happening well enough to explain it clearly myself. Just putting your values doesn't work on an arbitrary svg.

Answer (score 26):

You can import SVGs directly as React components and use them in `<SvgIcon>`:

```
import React from "react";
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from "./logo.svg";
import SvgIcon from "@material-ui/core/SvgIcon";

const App = () => (
  <SvgIcon>
    <Logo />
  </SvgIcon>
);

export default App;
```

See also: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs

Unfortunately React seems not able to render all kind of SVGs (e.g. modified with Inkscape, Illustrator) yet. But at least the default `logo.svg` inside a `create-react-app` project works.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer worked for me! Guess this is familiar to you, but if somebody wants to use InkScape or Illustrator svgs with React, you can do this using the https://github.com/svg/svgo client.

Answer (score 8):

To obtain the path for SvgIcon, open svg file with the text editor and copy the corresponding path expression.

Answer (score 8):

## For Vite users

Install [vite-plugin-svgr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-svgr)

```bash
npm i -D vite-plugin-svgr
```

In `vite.config.ts`

```
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr'

export default {
  // ...
  plugins: [svgr()],
}
```

Add a declaration in `src/vite-env.d.ts` if you use typescript.

```
/// <reference types="vite-plugin-svgr/client" />
```

Now you can use your SVG as

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './logo.svg'

// ...
<SvgIcon component={Logo} inheritViewBox />
```

Answer (score 5):

The `SvgIcon` is not meant for this purpose. More on this @ [Github](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/1545).

You are probably looking for this `startIcon={<img src={google}></img>}`

```
import google from "../../Assets/img/google.svg";
import GitHubIcon from "@material-ui/icons/GitHub";
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
         root: {
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "column",
                margin: theme.spacing(1),
                },
          button: {
               margin: "0.5rem",
                  },
          googleStyle: {
                fillColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
                    },
              }));

export default function ContainedButtons() {
  const classes = useStyles();
   return (
  <div>
  <Button
    variant="contained"
    color="secondary"
    className={classes.button}
    startIcon={<img src={google}></img>}
  >
    Login With Google
  </Button>
  <Button
    variant="contained"
    color="secondary"
    className={classes.button}
    startIcon={<GitHubIcon />}
  >
    Login with GitHub
  </Button>
</div>
);
}
```

Comment: This is probably the correct answer. Definitely should be higher up. Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The solution that worked for me is the following

```
 import React from 'react';
 import pure from 'recompose/pure';
 import {SvgIcon} from '@material-ui/core';

 let smile = (props) => (
   <SvgIcon {...props} >
<path d="M256,32C132.281,32,32,132.281,32,256s100.281,224,224,224s224-100.281,224-224S379.719,32,256,32z M256,448
c-105.875,0-192-86.125-192-192S150.125,64,256,64s192,86.125,192,192S361.875,448,256,448z M160,192c0-26.5,14.313-48,32-48
s32,21.5,32,48c0,26.531-14.313,48-32,48S160,218.531,160,192z M288,192c0-26.5,14.313-48,32-48s32,21.5,32,48
c0,26.531-14.313,48-32,48S288,218.531,288,192z M384,288c-16.594,56.875-68.75,96-128,96c-59.266,0-111.406-39.125-128-96"/>
   </SvgIcon>
 );

 smile = pure(smile);
 smile.displayName = 'smile';     
 smile.muiName = 'SvgIcon';

 export default smile;
```

[Check this example of material ui icon](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/56c113217d7d05d8bb0712771b727df81984d04b/src/svg-icons/action/face.js)

Comment: what is ````import pure from recompose/pure ?```

Answer (score 2):

If making more than one icon, you may not want to repeat all the boilerplate in the example referenced in the accepted answer.  You can use a wrapper component generator like:

```
const wrapSvgPath = (path, viewBox='0 0 24 24') => (props) => (
    <SvgIcon {...props} viewBox={viewBox}>{path}</SvgIcon>
)
```

used like:

```
const facebookPath = (<path
        d="M17,2V2H17V6H15C14.31,6 14,6.81 14,7.5V10H14L17,10V14H14V22H10V14H7V10H10V6A4,4 0 0,1 14,2H17Z" />
)
export const FacebookIcon = wrapSvgPath(facebookPath)
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to Christos' answer, make sure the `viewBox` is set to the dimensions that `mui` is giving the `svg` element or you might get the object clipped.

For example, when trying to put one of the [Discord](https://discord.com/branding) svgs into an `IconButton`, I was getting:

```
<svg width="71" height="55"...
```

But until I set the `viewBox` properly, was only getting the top left corner of the icon actually visible. After setting:

```
<SvgIcon component={DiscordIcon} viewBox="0 0 71 55" />
```

That then meant everything was visible and adapting the size of the `IconButton` worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Open your svg file in a editor (example: vscode). You will see a file structure of something similar like this ->

```
<svg width="27" height="28" viewBox="0 0 27 28" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M5.91942 27.5138L6.15827 26.984L8.69599 21.1562H8.68852L13.5027 10.3812L18.3542 21.1562H18.3467L21.1083 27.5138H26.2509L15.8687 4.72523L13.5698 0L0.933594 27.5138H5.91942Z" fill="#A7A9AC"/>
</svg>
```

Then go to your react components, replace path with your own path. This should work. Add styles for custom change of design.

Answer (score 1):

```js
import SvgIcon from '@material-ui/core/SvgIcon'
import Register from "./../../media/register.svg"
import React from 'react';

const getSvgIconMaterial = (Icon: string, props?: any) => {
    return (
        <SvgIcon component="object">
            <embed type="image/svg+xml" src={Icon} style={{ height: "100%" }} />
        </SvgIcon>
    );
};
```

use like this

```js
<>{getSvgIconMaterial(Register)}</>
```

Probably not perfect but works nicely. Maybe add a small padding/margin.
[image: React SVG Custom Component]

Answer (score 1):

Pull the image into your button file using import. Use an Avatar to render the image and then put that in the Button.

```
import logo from "../assets/logoWhite.svg";

const title = "Click me"

<Button>
       <Avatar src={logo} alt="logo" sx={{ width: 24, height: 24 }} />
       {title}
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

import svg file to your react application folder .
Then in the file / component in which you want to use the svg icon use

```
import { ReactComponent as MyIcon } from '../svgiconfolder/myicon.svg'

export function MyCompnent(){return <MyIcon />}
```

if you want to change colour use

```
import {ReactComponent as MyIcon} from '../svgiconfolder/myicon.svg'

export function MyCompnent(){return <MyIcon fill="#00000"/>}//use the color code in fill or if there is any color attribute in svg file try to use that
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a small utility tool to convert most SVGs to Material UI icons easily:
[SVG to MUI icon](https://www.fernand-veyrier.xyz/svg-to-mui).
It will optimize your SVG, convert paths and most other objects into a Functional component that you can just copy paste in your project.