# How to load external svg file in `SvgIcon` in material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using `SvgIcon` in a react app from `material-ui` https://material-ui.com/api/svg-icon/. All examples in the document are `<path d="M10 20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12 3 2 12h3v8z" />`. I don't know what it is. How can I use this component to render a svg from external file?

I have checked this post [How to use an SVG file in a SvgIcon in Material-UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510443/how-to-use-an-svg-file-in-a-svgicon-in-material-ui) but it doesn't give an answer to load external files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use an SVG file in a SvgIcon in Material-UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510443/how-to-use-an-svg-file-in-a-svgicon-in-material-ui)

Comment: I have checked it but it doesn't give an answer to load external files.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to use Path to load external svg. You should use `<img />` inside de `<Icon>` according to this [answer](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15452#issuecomment-522665796) in github:

In the ['@Christos-Lytras' answer there is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510443/how-to-use-an-svg-file-in-a-svgicon-in-material-ui#answer-56418369) on how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You may import svg icon as a react component and use this component wrapped inside the SvgIcon component:

```
import { ReactComponent as Car } from './icons/car.svg'
...
<SvgIcon>
  <Car />
</SvgIcon>
```