# How would I change my SVG color with media queries?

Tags: css, svg, media-queries

I need to change my logo color to black, instead of white, when the screen is small than 992px. Much easier than showing and hiding 2 different images, I think.

I tried adding this in the .svg file style tags, but it seems to just use the white fill and doesn't get affected with screen resize.

```
<style type="text/css">     
.logo-color{fill:#FFFFFF;}

    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      .logo-color {
        fill:#000000;
      }
    }
</style>
<path class="logo-color"...etc..
```

Thanks for any help.

Edit:

I should state that I'm calling it with this, if it makes a difference:

```
<img src="css/img/logo.svg" alt="Logo" width="150" style="width:150px;">
```

Comment: Please provide the original SVG.

Comment: It should actually work. [Try it yourself](https://jsfiddle.net/gmj23ve2/).

Comment: you mean 'max-width' not 'min-width' if you want it to take effect under 992px

Comment: I added the full svg as per hungerstar request.  Also, MichaelB, if I add max instead, it just turns to black and not affected by screensize.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [img src SVG changing the fill color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933430/img-src-svg-changing-the-fill-color)

Comment: @hungerstar it still doesn't work after trying that jquery solution in your link.

Comment: @KeepCool then you didn't do it right. The main problem you're facing is that you can't update the SVG via CSS when the SVG is being included into the page via an `<img>`. You will need to inline your SVG to update the fill color as @insertusernamehere has demonstrated. Personally I wouldn't use the JS solution, just inline the SVG to begin with. Then apply CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine there are different approaches to this but here is one:

As per the `@media` query, when the screen width shrinks to less than `992px`, the logo will change from a black image on a white background to a white image on a black background.

```css
svg {
width: 414px;
height: 96px;
fill: rgb(0,0,0);
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
}

@media only screen and (max-width:992px) {
svg {
fill: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 413.1 96">
<path d="M0.7,81.8L0.7,81.8v-0.9c0.2-3.2,1.4-5,3.5-5.5h15.6c2.2,0.4,3.4,2.6,3.5,6.4h-2.8c-0.1-2.4-0.8-3.5-2.1-3.5
    H5.7c-1.2,0-1.9,1.1-2.1,3.2c0.2,1.9,0.9,2.8,2.1,2.8h14.2c2.1,0.5,3.3,2.2,3.5,5.3v0.7c-0.2,3.3-1.4,5.2-3.5,5.7H4.2
    c-2.2-0.4-3.4-2.6-3.5-6.4h2.8c0.1,2.4,0.8,3.5,2.1,3.5h12.7c1.2,0,1.9-1.1,2.1-3.2c-0.2-1.9-0.9-2.8-2.1-2.8H4.2
    C2.1,86.6,1,84.8,0.7,81.8L0.7,81.8z M81.2,95.9h-2.8V78.2h-8.5v-2.8h19.8v2.8h-8.5V95.9L81.2,95.9z M157.5,75.4v17
    c-0.5,2.4-2.8,3.5-7.1,3.5h-7.1c-4.3,0-6.6-1.2-7.1-3.5v-17h2.8V91c0,1.4,1.4,2.1,4.3,2.1h7.1c2.8,0,4.2-0.7,4.2-2.1V75.4H157.5
    L157.5,75.4z M206.9,78.2v14.9h13.4c1.4,0,2.1-1.4,2.1-4.3v-6.4c0-2.8-0.7-4.2-2.1-4.2H206.9L206.9,78.2z M204,95.9V75.4h17.7
    c2.4,0.5,3.5,2.8,3.5,7.1v6.4c0,4.3-1.2,6.6-3.5,7.1L204,95.9L204,95.9z M274.6,95.9h-2.8V75.4h2.8V95.9L274.6,95.9z M326.1,78.2
    c-1.4,0-2.1,1.4-2.1,4.2v6.4c0,2.8,0.7,4.3,2.1,4.3h12.7c1.4,0,2.1-1.4,2.1-4.3v-6.4c0-2.8-0.7-4.2-2.1-4.2H326.1L326.1,78.2z
     M324.7,95.9c-2.4-0.5-3.5-2.8-3.5-7.1v-6.4c0-4.2,1.2-6.6,3.5-7.1h15.6c2.4,0.5,3.5,2.8,3.5,7.1v6.4c0,4.3-1.2,6.6-3.5,7.1H324.7
    L324.7,95.9z M390.4,81.8L390.4,81.8v-0.9c0.2-3.2,1.4-5,3.5-5.5h15.6c2.2,0.4,3.4,2.6,3.5,6.4h-2.8c-0.1-2.4-0.8-3.5-2.1-3.5h-12.7
    c-1.2,0-1.9,1.1-2.1,3.2c0.2,1.9,0.9,2.8,2.1,2.8h14.2c2.1,0.5,3.3,2.2,3.5,5.3v0.7c-0.2,3.3-1.4,5.2-3.5,5.7H394
    c-2.2-0.4-3.4-2.6-3.5-6.4h2.8c0.1,2.4,0.8,3.5,2.1,3.5H408c1.2,0,1.9-1.1,2.1-3.2c-0.2-1.9-0.9-2.8-2.1-2.8h-14.2
    C391.8,86.6,390.6,84.8,390.4,81.8z" />
<path d="M20.5,24.1h43.2c26.7,0,26.6,36.6,0,36.6H1.2v-11h59.6c9.8,0,9.7-13.8,1-13.8H19.9C-6.6,35.9-6.6,0,19.9,0
    c57.7,0,114.6,0,172.2,0c6,0,10.3,0.9,13,2.8c2.7,1.8,4.1,4.8,4.1,9V26c0,4.1-1.3,7.2-4.1,9.1c-2.7,1.9-7,2.8-13,2.8h-9.9l34.9,22.9
    h-25.2l-44.5-33.3h36.9c3,0,5.1-0.3,6.3-1.1c1.1-0.7,1.7-2,1.7-3.8v-7.3c0-1.8-0.5-3-1.7-3.7c-1.1-0.7-3.2-1.1-6.3-1.1
    c-21.1,0-40.7,0.8-61.9,0.8v49.5h-17.6V11.3C76.7,11.3,49,11,20.7,11C13.7,11,13.8,24.1,20.5,24.1L20.5,24.1z M354,23.9l0.1-8
    c0.1-7.2,5.5-5.3,10.7-5.6h46.8V0h-50.9h-6.9c-6,0-10.4,1-13.1,2.8c-2.7,1.9-4.1,4.9-4.1,9.1v11.6v14.2v11.6c0,4.1,1.4,7.2,4.1,9.1
    c2.7,1.9,7,2.8,13.1,2.8l14-0.4h44.6V49.3l-51.6,1.2c-4.9-0.1-6.4-0.1-6.6-5.1c-0.1-1.5-0.2-9.7-0.2-11.2h57.3V23.9H354L354,23.9z
     M306.3,10.6c-19,0-37.9-0.1-56.8-0.1V0h64.6c6,0,10.4,1,13.1,2.8c2.7,1.9,4.1,4.9,4.1,9.1v13.5c0,4.1-1.4,7.1-4.1,9
    s-7,2.8-13.1,2.8h-47.3v23.6h-17.3V26.5c19,0,37.8,0.2,56.8,0.2c3,0,5.1-0.4,6.2-1.1s1.7-2,1.7-3.7v-6.5c0-1.8-0.6-3-1.7-3.7
    C311.4,10.9,309.3,10.6,306.3,10.6L306.3,10.6z M224,60.7V0h17.6v60.7H224z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks.  To anyone else who has the same issue in the future, I put the plain svg code directly in the html (without all the xml stuff and styling), then put the css either in the head or the css file. I also put the background-color to "none" so it keeps it's transparency.   Thanks Rounin!

Comment: This won't work if the SVG is used as an image i.e. via an <img> tag.

Comment: Note: When _"inline the SVG"_ is mentioned, this means the SVG should be embedded in the html.

Answer (score 1):

Embed svg code in html instead add it as image and it will work

Comment: Thanks. How do I embed it in my html but then insert it as an image also. Not sure I understand.

Comment: @KeepCool You can't. If you want to style the contents of the SVG it has to be inline.