# CSS animation do not work for svg in <img>

Tags: html, image, css, svg

I am trying to animate an SVG in image/object tag but it is not working

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.rotate-45 {
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.rotate {
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: rotate 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.rotate-back {
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: rotate 1s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

.left {
  animation: move 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.right {
  animation: move 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(calc(90deg + 45deg));
  }
}

@keyframes move {
  50% {
    transform: translate(-30px, -30px);
  }
}
```

```html
 <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g transform="translate(500,500)">
      <rect class="rotate-45 rotate-back" x="-5" y="-5" width="10" height="10" stroke="#00a99d" stroke-width="20" fill="none" />
      <rect class="rotate-45 rotate" x="-50" y="-50" width="100" height="100" stroke="#00a99d" stroke-width="20" stroke-linejoin="bevel" fill="none" />
      <g transform="translate(-50,0) rotate(-45)">
        <polyline class="left" points="40,-40 50,-50 -40,-50 -50,-40 -50,50 -40,40" stroke="#00a99d" stroke-width="20" fill="none" />
      </g>
      <g transform="translate(50,0) rotate(135)">
        <polyline class="right" points="40,-40 50,-50 -40,-50 -50,-40 -50,50 -40,40" stroke="#00a99d" stroke-width="20" fill="none" />
      </g>
      <text y="-140" text-anchor="middle" font-weight="bold" font-size="3em" font-family="sans-serif">loading data...</text>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

How to animate the SVG inside the image tag along side with CSS

Here is a plunker for that code https://plnkr.co/edit/TdfR7cpVaQArtcUs0Hro?p=preview

Comment: you titles says nothing about the problem. please specifically explain in the title your issue in short

Comment: you seem to want help in doing CSS animation, this has nothing to do with SVG.

Comment: Include your CSS in your svg directly, html's document's CSS can't target img's content : https://plnkr.co/edit/dtjUhZpzbm3NjdzsBKch?p=preview

Comment: You can also use `<?xml-stylesheet href="style.css" type="text/css"?>` if you dont want to have to embed it for `img` tags to work. The above code will work in an `object` tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [img src SVG changing the fill color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933430/img-src-svg-changing-the-fill-color)

Comment: @Deckerz, `<img>` tags are not allowed to load external resources though.

Comment: @Kaiido did you not read my entire message? I said if you dont want to have to embed it for `img` tags to work. This works in an `object` tag

Comment: @Deckerz I wasn't sure what *"if you dont want to have to embed it for `img` tag"* really meant.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. got the solution.  Can someone post an answer to close this question? Another doubt is that can the style used inside this svg have its effect on other elements

Comment: @Kaiido fair enough my bad with wording then

Comment: @Kaiido. I am using your answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't animate the internals of an `<img>` from the outside. Even if it is an SVG. There are two reasons for this:

1. CSS doesn't apply across document boundaries, and
2. Images referenced via an `<img>` must be self contained.

Animations should work if you put the CSS inside the external SVG (in a `<style>` element as normal).

Note also that you will need to change the way you do `transform-origin`. The way it works in Chrome is convenient, but it is wrong according to the current spec.  It won't work on other browsers like Firefox.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <style>
.rotate-45 {
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.rotate {
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  animation: rotate 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.rotate-back {
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  animation: rotate 1s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

.left {
  animation: move 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.right {
  animation: move 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
}

@keyframes move {
  50% {
    transform: translate(-30px, -30px);
  }
}
  </style>
  <g transform="translate(500,500)">
    <rect class="rotate-45 rotate-back" x="-5" y="-5" width="10" height="10" stroke="#00a99d" stroke-width="20" fill="none"/>
    <rect class="rotate-45 rotate" x="-50" y="-50" width="100" height="100" stroke="#00a99d" stroke-width="20" stroke-linejoin="bevel" fill="none"/>
    <g transform="translate(-50,0) rotate(-45)"><polyline class="left" points="40,-40 50,-50 -40,-50 -50,-40 -50,50 -40,40" stroke="#00a99d" stroke-width="20" fill="none"/></g>
    <g transform="translate(50,0) rotate(135)"><polyline class="right" points="40,-40 50,-50 -40,-50 -50,-40 -50,50 -40,40" stroke="#00a99d" stroke-width="20" fill="none"/></g>
    <text y="-140" text-anchor="middle" font-weight="bold" font-size="3em" font-family="sans-serif">loading data...</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: A doubt is that can the style used inside this svg have its effect on other elements

Comment: No. As I said. CSS doesn't work across document boundaries. This is true whether it is an SVG or anything else.

Comment: If you save the snippet's code to let's say "example.com/icon.svg" and then try to add it to some HTML document by doing this: <img src="example.com/icon.svg"> then the animations work as expected in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari or iOS! Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<?xml-stylesheet href="style.css" type="text/css"?>` if you **dont** want to have to embed it for `img` tags to work. The above code will work in an `object` tag

If you want `img` tags to work do what Kaiido suggested and embed it.

Comment: Please could you expose your solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with pure JavaScript or some other environment that doesn't automatically include SVG's inline in your HTML output (eg like `create-react-app` does), here's a solution that might come in handy for you:

```html
<img id="logo" src="logo.svg" />
<script>
// load logo inline for animation on hover
const loadLogo = async () => {
  // get logo, parse source text, and insert text into doc
  document.write(await (await fetch("logo.svg")).text());
  // remove fallback img logo
  document.querySelector("img#logo").remove();
};
loadLogo();
</script>
```

All this does is attempt to load an image at a given url/path, then insert its text contents right into the document, in place. Then you can style it from other style sheets, manipulate sub-elements with javascript, have user interaction animations, and etc. If it fails to load for any reason, there is an `<img>` there as a backup.

This could be written to be more general too, but this was just a quick solution I used once.

---

Another solution is to just embed the SVG using `<object>` [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50157634/2180570), though that could have some limitations depending on what you want to do.