# Fill color svg image

Tags: css

How properly use SVG images? I tried to change color of my white svg image but it does not affect.

HTML:

```
<div class="issue__favorite">
  <i class="favorite"></i>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.issue__favorite {
  .favorite {
    width: 17px;
    height: 16px;
    display: block;
    background-size: 17px 16px;
    background: url(../../../../../assets/images/icon-star.svg);      
  }
}
```

Edit:

Also is there a way to set border of figure, that's is in svg image?

Comment: you need to use it as an SVG or Font, not image

Comment: Please Follow below Link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933430/img-src-svg-changing-the-fill-color