# Changing color of an inline SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I downloaded a world map SVG to mess around with SVG manipulation with Javascript.  My goal is to change the color of the United States when I click on it, and then when I click on it again it goes back to the original color.  Here is the part of the SVG that defines the United States:

```
<path
inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
id="US"
data-name="United States"
data-id="US"
d="m 116.7,450.7 2,-0.9 2.5,-1.4 0.2,-0.4 -0.9,-2.2 -0.7,-0.8 
-7.1,-0.5 -6.2,-1.6 -4.8,0.5 -4.9,-0.9 2,-1.2 -6.3,-0.3 -3.3,1 
0.5,-2.4 z"
style="fill:#f2f2f2;fill-rule:evenodd" />
```

(I deleted a lot of the coordinates because they were making the code so long)

Here is the CSS:

```
.united_states {
 fill: blue;
}
```

Here is the javascript, using JQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $('#US').click(function(event){
    console.log("You just clicked on the United States!!");

 $('#US').toggle();
 $(this).toggleClass('.united_states');

  });
})();
```

And finally, here is a JsFiddle of it: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/L0r5e2fg/1/)

Changing the 'fill' attribute of the  tag to blue worked, but I want to do it on click, and toggle it (blue and then back to normal).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `$obj.toggle()` will toggle its `display` CSSProperty between `block` and `none`. Probably not what you want. Now, you do have a `fill` rule set in the element's `style` attribute. This rule will have precedence over the `.united_states` class selector, and hence, your rule won't get updated. You could arrange it in many ways, like not setting `style` attributes but `fill` attribute directly, or setting it all in a global stylesheet, or (the less good) by adding an `!important` keyword to rule class' rule...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [img src SVG changing the fill color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933430/img-src-svg-changing-the-fill-color)

Comment: @Kalido Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace jQuery `toggleClass`. Instead you can use `classlist` property and then toggle it

See below:

```
(function($){
  $('#US').click(function(event){
    console.log("You just clicked on the United States!!");

  $(this).prop("classList").toggle("united_states");
  });
})(jQuery);
```

CSS:

```
.united_states {
 fill: blue !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L0r5e2fg/13/

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't really need another answer, but I am doing so because the changes you need to make ought to be explained, so you know why they were needed:

1. First remove `$('#US').toggle();`. It was causing that element to be hidden. You don't want that.
2. Remove the dot/period from your class name in `toggleClass()`. It is not required here:

   ```
   $(this).toggleClass('united_states');
   ```
3. However this still doesn't make the `toggleClass()` work.  This is because the map file already has a fill colour defined using a `style=""` attribute.  `style` attributes have a higher precedence than CSS rules, so your `.united_states {...}` rule is not doing anything.

   To resolve this, you need to tell the browser that your CSS rule should override the `style` attribute. You can do this by adding `!important` to the CSS property:

   ```
   .united_states {
     fill: blue !important;
   }
   ```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L0r5e2fg/18/)

Comment: Yeah it was stupid to have the $("#US').toggle(); line.  Thank you for the help and I really appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

**JS**

```
$(function(){
  $('#US').click(function(event){
    $(this).toggleClass('united_states');
  });
})();
```

**CSS**

```
.united_states {
 fill: blue !important;
}
```