# How to change the fill color of svg image that contain in <img> tag

Tags: javascript, html, svg, colors, picker

I am adding images dynamically into specific div,
like that:

```
<img class="image"  id='logo' src='js/whiteboard/images/square.svg'  alt=""  style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
```

but I have no idea how to change the inside color of the SVG image

I'm doing by this JS code, but no success:

```
var colorPicker = document.getElementById("colorpicker");
colorPicker.addEventListener('change', function() {             
    $("svg").find('path, text').css('fill', this.value);            
});
```

Comment: @GaryThomas but i am changing the color with js

Comment: but the duplicate one is JS, specially this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43015413/8732818