# Dynamically insert SVG with php?

Tags: php, svg

I am trying to reference/insert a dynamically uploaded svg file (image) from a products database using PHP.  So far uploading the images work fine, as I can use them with an image tag and they show up fine.

```
<img src="image.svg" />
```

The XML also shows up correctly when I open them on my computer (using a text editor for example).

The problem is I can't seem to get them to be displayed inline so I can use styles like **fill**.

Here is my PHP code that dynamically displays the image:

```
<svg id="svg-image" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
   <image id="main-image" xlink:href="<?php echo tep_href_link('images/' . $product_info['products_image']); ?>" />
</svg>
```

I tried changing image to path in the above code to get it to work, and the image just disappears on reload.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is not the PHP. Please take a look at this question: [img src SVG changing the fill color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933430/img-src-svg-changing-the-fill-color): 15 Answers

Comment: Yes I know about img src not allowing the fill color code, which is why I am trying to change my PHP code to spit out the correct SVG code.  I'm just not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Just include the .svg file, without any wrapper. As long as you can set width and height in a stylesheet, it should just work.

Comment: And how do I "just include the svg file"?  This is a dynamically created page from PHP.  That's what I'm not clear on in the first place - how to programatically include the file.