# Change fill color of svg in special constellation

Tags: html, css, image, svg

I am loading an SVG like this:

```
<img src="./home.svg" height="30px" width="auto"></img>
```

Here is a example SVG:

```
<svg class="svg_p" width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"><path d="M9 23h-5.991c-.553 0-1.001-.448-1.001-1s.448-1 1.001-1h2v-1h-2c-.553 0-1.001-.448-1.001-1s.448-1 1.001-1h2v-1h-2c-.553 0-1.001-.448-1.001-1s.448-1 1.001-1h18.008c.552 0 1 .448 1 1s-.448 1-1 1h-2.001v1h2.001c.552 0 1 .448 1 1s-.448 1-1 1h-2.001v1h2.001c.552 0 1 .448 1 1s-.448 1-1 1h-6.003v-6h-6.014v6zm13.172-9h-20.302l10.124-8.971 10.178 8.971zm-10.169-13s9.046 7.911 11.672 10.244c.413.367.45.999.083 1.412-.367.413-.996.445-1.412.083-2.421-2.105-10.343-9.063-10.343-9.063s-7.899 6.893-10.327 9.051c-.413.367-1.046.329-1.413-.083-.367-.413-.329-1.045.083-1.412 2.626-2.333 11.657-10.232 11.657-10.232zm.01 7c1.104 0 2 .896 2 2s-.896 2-2 2c-1.105 0-2.001-.896-2.001-2s.896-2 2.001-2zm7.003-5h2.984v5.128l-2.984-2.59v-2.538z"/></svg>
```

Now I want to change the color via CSS. Here is the Code for that:

```
.svg_p path {
    fill: var(--text-color);
}
```

The only problem is that it does not work. It works when I put the SVG directly with itself tag  into the HTML, but I want to do this with my solution at the beginning of my post. Is this possible?
~filip

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933430/img-src-svg-changing-the-fill-color

Comment: @enxaneta Is there a pure JS Code too?