# How inherit stroke color in SVG? (Not fill, but stroke color)

Tags: svg, colors, stroke

I have an .SVG where I call with `<img src="/image/arrow.svg" alt="Arrow">`. Everything is good, but I would like to dynamically set a different stroke color (Not fill color...) for my SVG like `<img ... style="color:red">`. I read that I could use fill="currentColor" on my path,but how could I do for my stroke color?

My SVG file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" height="100" width="100">
    <path d="M20 10 H90 V80" fill="transparent" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="20" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
    <path d="M10 90 L100 0" fill="transparent" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="20" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
</svg>
```

My html:

```
<img src="/image/arrow.svg" alt="Arrow" style="color:red">
```

Comment: images cannot inherit things from the host document. You could put the markup inline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [Robert Lognson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson) correctly stated, and [previously discussed on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933430/img-src-svg-changing-the-styles-with-css), svg used as an image element has a new image context, thus it does not use the document's styles, whereas an inline svg element does use them.

So the following example works:

```css
svg.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<svg class="red" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" height="100" width="100">
    <path d="M20 10 H90 V80" fill="transparent" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="20" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
    <path d="M10 90 L100 0" fill="transparent" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="20" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
</svg>
```