# How to change svg hover color using img style property?

Tags: html

```
<img alt='PDF' src='document.svg' style=''>
```

what should be filled in the above *style* property to change the svg hover color without using CSS?

Comment: `style` literally contains CSS, so you can't put there anything else. Also since it's `<img>` and not direct `<svg>`, you can only style that image, but not contents of it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [img src SVG changing the styles with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933430/img-src-svg-changing-the-styles-with-css)

Comment: @Justinas but I could add width, height inside that style, why cannot add hover?

Comment: @J.W You cannot add hover in style because hover is mouse event.

Comment: You set width and height for `<img>` itself, not for SVG document!

Answer (score 0):

You can't affect SVG images like that.

There are a lot of different ways to use SVG. Depending on which way, the tactic for recoloring that SVG in different states or conditions — :hover, :active, :focus, class name change, etc — is different.

**Method 1 - SVG Symbol / Use**

HTML :-

```
<div>
  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="#bike" />
  </svg>
  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="#bell" />
  </svg>
  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="#arrow" />
  </svg>
</div>
<svg display="none">
  <symbol width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="bike">
    <path d="M5,20.5A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 1.5,17A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 5,13.5A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 8.5,17A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 5,20.5M5,12A5,5 0 0,0 0,17A5,5 0 0,0 5,22A5,5 0 0,0 10,17A5,5 0 0,0 5,12M14.8,10H19V8.2H15.8L13.86,4.93C13.57,4.43 13,4.1 12.4,4.1C11.93,4.1 11.5,4.29 11.2,4.6L7.5,8.29C7.19,8.6 7,9 7,9.5C7,10.13 7.33,10.66 7.85,10.97L11.2,13V18H13V11.5L10.75,9.85L13.07,7.5M19,20.5A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 15.5,17A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 19,13.5A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 22.5,17A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 19,20.5M19,12A5,5 0 0,0 14,17A5,5 0 0,0 19,22A5,5 0 0,0 24,17A5,5 0 0,0 19,12M16,4.8C17,4.8 17.8,4 17.8,3C17.8,2 17,1.2 16,1.2C15,1.2 14.2,2 14.2,3C14.2,4 15,4.8 16,4.8Z"></path>
  </symbol>
  <symbol width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="bell">
    <path d="M11.5,22C11.64,22 11.77,22 11.9,21.96C12.55,21.82 13.09,21.38 13.34,20.78C13.44,20.54 13.5,20.27 13.5,20H9.5A2,2 0 0,0 11.5,22M18,10.5C18,7.43 15.86,4.86 13,4.18V3.5A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 11.5,2A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 10,3.5V4.18C7.13,4.86 5,7.43 5,10.5V16L3,18V19H20V18L18,16M19.97,10H21.97C21.82,6.79 20.24,3.97 17.85,2.15L16.42,3.58C18.46,5 19.82,7.35 19.97,10M6.58,3.58L5.15,2.15C2.76,3.97 1.18,6.79 1,10H3C3.18,7.35 4.54,5 6.58,3.58Z"></path>
  </symbol>
  <symbol width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="arrow">
    <path d="M4,11V13H16L10.5,18.5L11.92,19.92L19.84,12L11.92,4.08L10.5,5.5L16,11H4Z"></path>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

CSS:-

```
svg {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
}
svg:hover {
    fill: red;
}
```

**Method 2 - Inline SVG**
HTML :-

```
<div>
  <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M5,20.5A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 1.5,17A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 5,13.5A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 8.5,17A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 5,20.5M5,12A5,5 0 0,0 0,17A5,5 0 0,0 5,22A5,5 0 0,0 10,17A5,5 0 0,0 5,12M14.8,10H19V8.2H15.8L13.86,4.93C13.57,4.43 13,4.1 12.4,4.1C11.93,4.1 11.5,4.29 11.2,4.6L7.5,8.29C7.19,8.6 7,9 7,9.5C7,10.13 7.33,10.66 7.85,10.97L11.2,13V18H13V11.5L10.75,9.85L13.07,7.5M19,20.5A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 15.5,17A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 19,13.5A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 22.5,17A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 19,20.5M19,12A5,5 0 0,0 14,17A5,5 0 0,0 19,22A5,5 0 0,0 24,17A5,5 0 0,0 19,12M16,4.8C17,4.8 17.8,4 17.8,3C17.8,2 17,1.2 16,1.2C15,1.2 14.2,2 14.2,3C14.2,4 15,4.8 16,4.8Z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M11.5,22C11.64,22 11.77,22 11.9,21.96C12.55,21.82 13.09,21.38 13.34,20.78C13.44,20.54 13.5,20.27 13.5,20H9.5A2,2 0 0,0 11.5,22M18,10.5C18,7.43 15.86,4.86 13,4.18V3.5A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 11.5,2A1.5,1.5 0 0,0 10,3.5V4.18C7.13,4.86 5,7.43 5,10.5V16L3,18V19H20V18L18,16M19.97,10H21.97C21.82,6.79 20.24,3.97 17.85,2.15L16.42,3.58C18.46,5 19.82,7.35 19.97,10M6.58,3.58L5.15,2.15C2.76,3.97 1.18,6.79 1,10H3C3.18,7.35 4.54,5 6.58,3.58Z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M4,11V13H16L10.5,18.5L11.92,19.92L19.84,12L11.92,4.08L10.5,5.5L16,11H4Z"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

CSS :-

```
svg {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
}
svg:hover {
    fill: red;
}
```