# Where to put images with SvelteKit

Tags: image, sveltekit

I have been using Svelte for a little while and now I have switched to SvelteKit so I can add multiple pages. I want to add some images to my site but I don't know where to put them. In Svelte I would just put them in `public/images` but there is no `public` folder with SvelteKit (I set it up with `npm init svelte@next my-app`  if that matters). Would I put them in `static`?

Thanks!

Comment: Both is an option, `static` and `lib`. If you want to import them dynamically, you're  better off using `lib` (e.g. when they're part of a component). But having a bunch of "dump images" just lying around in `static` is not wrong either. Whatever suits you, I would say.

Comment: @b2m9 thanks for your comment. How would I reference them if I used `static`? I tried `../../static/image.png` but it didn't work. I also tried looking up how to use a `lib` but I didn't find anything really helpful. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: `static` is your root folder after the build step. So when you put an image into `status/img/photo.jpg`, you can reference it via `/img/photo.jpg`.

Comment: @b2m9 what is the opposite of importing images dynamically, i.e. how can an image NOT be part of a component?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I recommend putting images under `src/lib`, not `static`. For example you could make a `src/lib/images` or `src/lib/assets` folder and put them there.

The reason is performance:

For files imported from anywhere under `src`, at compile time Vite adds a hash to the filename. `myImage.png` might end up as `myImage-a89cfcb3.png`. The hash is based on the image contents. So if you change the image, it gets a new hash. This enables the server to send a *very* long cache expiration to the browser, so the browser can cache it forever or until it changes. It's key-based cache expiration, which IMO is the best kind: cached exactly as long as it needs to be. (Whether the server actually sends the right caching headers in the response may depend on which SvelteKit adapter you use and what host you're on.)

By contrast, images under `static` don't have a hash added to their name. You can use the `static` directory for things like `robots.txt` that need to have a specific filename. Since the filename stays unchanged even if its contents change, these files by necessity end up having a `cache-control` value that includes `max-age=0, must-revalidate` and an `etag`, which means even if the browser caches the image it still has to make a server round-trip to validate that the cached image is correct. This slows down every image on your site.

#### Usage:

When putting images under `src/lib`, you reference them like this:

```html
<script>
import img from '$lib/images/img.png';
</script>

<img src={img} alt="Image" />
```

I recommend simplifying by adding [svelte-preprocess-import-assets](https://github.com/bluwy/svelte-preprocess-import-assets) to your project, which automates the process of importing images and cleans up your code. You write the following and it generates the code above:

```html
<img src="$lib/images/img.png" alt="Image" />
```

Comment: How are you redefining [%sveltekit.assets%](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/master/documentation/docs/10-getting-started/30-project-structure.md) with this approach or are you ignoring that prop? It's used in the default `app.html` of `create-svelte`

Comment: Good question. I'm not redefining %sveltekit.assets%. It's still there for static assets and still references the `static` directory. I just personally wouldn't use it except for favicon and robots.txt.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in SvelteKit using vite `v4.0.0`...

Comment: How would i go about if I have lib/images/first/1.jpg and .2.jpg AND lib/images/second/1.jpg and 2.jpg. >> Then I want to have a dynamic route (xyz.com/first) and fetch all images in "first" folder dynamically. Is it OK to use a dynamic impor this way? Or would I lose performance / break something?

Comment: @JackWestmore I would try upgrading Vite. It would be strange for it not to work--it's a basic feature of Vite. I'm using it successfully with Vite v4.0.4.

Comment: @userRR For your use case I think putting the images under /static is still the best option and just use `<img src={\`/static/${slug}/1.jpg\`}`. I don't think Vite supports dynamic imports of images using `import(url)`.

Comment: [Sveltekit documentation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#files) implicitly supports this answer: "`assets?: string;`:
a place to put static files that should have stable URLs and undergo no processing, such as `favicon.ico` or `manifest.json`"

Answer (score 44):

I added the images in `static/images` and referenced them with `src="/images/photo.jpg"` like @b2m9 said and it works perfectly.

Comment: One thing to note is that you have to reference this literally with the `src` attribute. I was under the impression that you had to import the image, Vite style.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't even know you could import images. I have updated my answer.

Comment: This answer can be improved. See: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/assets , https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#files , https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/project-structure

Comment: @Wtower that's a bit vague. Probably worth mentioning specifically what you'd add.

Answer (score 4):

As [Sveltekit](https://kit.svelte.dev/) uses [Vitejs](https://vitejs.dev/), there is a easy solution mentioned in **Vitejs** official web site ([Click Here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url)).
*First inside the script tag :*

```html
<script>
const imgUrl = new URL('./img.png', import.meta.url).href
</script>
```

*then inside your Image tag just use that variable,*

```html
<img src="{imgUrl}" alt="" />
```

*or,*

```html
<div class=" h-screen w-full" style="background-image: url('{bgUrl}') ;">
</div>
```

You can import static images from any relative path.

Answer (score -2):

there is also svelte-image.

"Svelte image is a pre-processor which automates image optimization using sharp.

It parses your `img` tags, optimizes or inlines them and replaces `src` accordingly. (External images are not optimized.)

Image component enables `lazyloading` and serving multiple sizes via `srcset`.

This package is heavily inspired by `gatsby` image.

Kudos to @jkdoshi for great video tutorial to Svelte Image."

-https://github.com/matyunya/svelte-image