# How to change the color of a svg img?

Tags: css, svg

I would like to change the color of a svg image `<img src="someImage.svg" className="icon">` to `#ffffff`. I tried using `color` and `fill` but both didn't work.

Currently I style it with `filter`. It works but I don't want to use it as it is too vague:

```
.icon {
filter: invert(100%) sepia(7%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(158deg)
        brightness(108%) contrast(109%);
}
```

Comment: I think this was answered before here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933430/img-src-svg-changing-the-styles-with-css

Comment: Are you able to put the SVG into your code? You can’t change fill etc of an svg brought in from a file as you have discovered.

Comment: Is this CSS-in-SVG, or CSS-in-HTML? Also, `<img className="icon" />` is not the correct attribute - it should be `<img class="icon"/>` - unless this is JSX for React?

Comment: I'm using react