# How to change group color of svg from jquery

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I have a svg image rendered on the browser like below.

```
<img src="../path/to/img/logo.svg"/>
```

Inside that `logo.svg`, the structure is like below.

```
<svg id="logo" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <g id="part-1">
        <path d="..." />
        <path d="..." />
    </g>

    <path d="..." fill="red" />
    <path d="..." fill="red" />
</svg>
```

I want to change `part-1` text-color (fill) from jquery. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the color of an svg element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element)

Comment: No. I already found that. But it doesn't.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the actual SVG file?

Comment: So you don't have access to the file apart from the <img> tag in the HTML document?

Comment: No. I don't have it.

Comment: **You can't change svg properties (e.g fill) in `<img>` elements:** [img src SVG changing the styles with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933430/img-src-svg-changing-the-styles-with-css). You need to either inline them directly in your body or use an external `<use>` element as described by [@northamerican](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933430/img-src-svg-changing-the-styles-with-css#51664058)

Comment: It's possible to fetch the file, then build an svg dom using a parser, then change properties within that dom, then convert the result to data uri, then replace the source in <img>

Answer (score 0):

Based on [How to change the color of an svg element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element) at answer with fore downvotes:

```
$('#logo > #part-1 > path').attr("fill", "white");
```

See also https://jsfiddle.net/reporter/zd92oahp/5/