# Leaflet SVG overlay - make paths interactive

Tags: javascript, svg, path, leaflet, mouseover

Is there any solution to make an svg `path` element which is loaded as an overlay on a leaflet map interactive? I want to change the color of the `path` on mouseover.

my suggestion was to try it with this code snippet:

SVG code:
`<path style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;" d="m 97.4375,132.5 c 0,0 -1.786197,3.39036 -0.875,6.6875 1.280573,4.63371 7.3125,4.5 7.3125,4.5" />`

the js I try to make the mouseover effect and popup in my leaflet overlay:

```
pathOverlay.setStyle('pointer-events: auto');

pathOverlay.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
    this.setAttribute('stroke-width', '3');
    this.setAttribute('stroke', 'red');
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [img src SVG changing the styles with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933430/img-src-svg-changing-the-styles-with-css)