# How to change svg instance color with javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg

I'm using vue to generate divs with many elements. One of those elements is .svg image. I want to be able to change color per .svg, for example, change color based on div's index.

I thought that with v-bind (dynamic class/style/anything else) I will be able to change color, but looks like I can't change svg's color with style.

I use `<img>`, not `<svg>`, not sure if it matters.

```css
.colored{
    background-color: orange; /* defines the background color of the image */
    mask: url(https://github.com/Dzhake/Dzhake/blob/main/pistol.svg) no-repeat center;
    -webkit-mask: url(https://github.com/Dzhake/Dzhake/blob/main/pistol.svg) no-repeat center / contain;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.colored2{
    background-color: orange; /* defines the background color of the image */
    mask: url(https://img.icons8.com/stackoverflow) no-repeat center;
    -webkit-mask: url(https://img.icons8.com/stackoverflow) no-repeat center / contain;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="colored"></div>
<div class="colored2"></div>
```

jsfiddle.net/k253t7o8/2 this is minimal reproducible example i think?

Comment: Please may you remove the comment and put the code into the question as a [mcve]?

Comment: _"I use <img>, not <svg>, not sure if it matters."_ - yes, it does. _Only_ if you have it embedded via <svg> directly in the HTML, can you then access parts of its content via your page's stylesheet. With _any_ mechanism that loads the SVG as an independent external resource, that is not possible. (In your example you are _not_ using <img>, btw. - you are using the SVG as a background-image. But in that case, the restrictions also apply - no formatting from the "outside" possible.)

Comment: in example I don't use <img> because I tried to use that evolutionbox suggested, sorry for confusing.
To use .svg I just need to copypaste <svg> in .html, right?

Comment: The question I linked also suggests using an SVG https://stackoverflow.com/a/34828163/989920

Comment: Sorry, it's not what I need, I need to change "instance", not all instances of .svg ... Right now I'm trying to make vue work with .svg, and I'm not sure if answer can be called "closed"... but it's more like vue problems.

Comment: Take inspiration from the [``<load-file>``](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd) **_native_ Web Component** I wrote. Works in Vue too.

Comment: You first icon doesn't work just because you can't access the svg from github. Create a public url (allowing cross origin access) via jsDelivr or a data URL and you can color your icon by changing the background-color. See [example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/YzgjWvy)

Answer (score 0):

One of the benefits of using Vue over vanilla HTML and CSS is the ability to use libraries that are purpose-built to solve these sorts of problems. Look into using [HeroIcons](https://heroicons.com/), and see if that addresses the problem you are having.

After installing the library, you can import whatever Icons you need in your component:

`import { HeartIcon } from '@heroicons/vue/24/outline';`

and style them using the `stroke` css property:

`<HeartIcon style="stroke: white;" />`