CSS style not working globally when converting SVG to ASCII and using it in image source
Okay, I have two sibling elements,
<div>
  <div class='test'>Hello, World!</div>
  <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,p...">
</div>

binary of that image look like something like,
<svg>
<style>
.test {
  fill: tomato;
  background-color: tomato;
}
</style>
...
</svg>

background color of the first div element is not changing. but if I directly use svg tag instead of img it works. is this how browser/HTML works? or can I achieve this?

https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#aa-the-problem-with-both-img-and-background-image: "The problem with both  and background-image…
Is that you don’t get to control the innards of the SVG with CSS"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933430/img-src-svg-changing-the-styles-with-css
